# Why isn't the error array returning when the if statement failed?

Tags: php

I'm using the below code to insert a new post into the database.

It's working almost flawlessly, the only issue is that the `return $this->errors[] = $image->getErrors();` is not being reported at all by php, even when I'm purposely uploading a .txt file when it's not allowed (only jpegs are).

Since `$image->isUploaded` return false if move_file_uploaded failed, the reports should get shown.

After the function is called, nothing is inserted into the database because the error is there, it's just not being reported.

But if I upload a correct jpeg image, the `$db->commit()` is successful and the `$image->isUploaded()` returns true and uploads the images to the server as there are no errors.

```
$public errors = [];

public function newPost($post_title, $post_category, $post_instructions, $post_instructionImages)
{

    $this->post_title             = $post_title;
    $this->post_category          = $post_category;
    $this->post_instructions      = $post_instructions;

    //this here just checks the $this reference to see if it's not empty
    $this->validate_post();

    if(empty($this->errors)){
        $db = static::getDB();

        $db->beginTransaction();
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO post (title, category ) VALUES (:title, :category)');
        $sth->bindValue(':title', $post_title, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sth->bindValue(':category', $post_category, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sth->execute();

        $postId = $db->lastInsertId();

        if(isset($post_instructions)){

            $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT into post_instructions (post_id, instructions) VALUES (:post_id, :instructions)');
            $sth->bindValue(':post_id', $postId, PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $sth->bindValue(':instructions', $data['instructions'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $sth->execute();

            $instructionsId = $db->lastInsertId();

            $uploadImage = new uploadImages();
            $image = $uploadImage->listen($post_instructionImages, 'uploads/post/img/instructions', 'instruction_');

            if($image->isUploaded()){
                $image_name = $image->getFileName();
                $sth = $db->prepare('UPDATE instructions SET image = :image WHERE id = :id');
                $sth->bindValue(':image', $image_name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $sth->bindValue(':id', $instructionsId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sth->execute();
            } else {
                return $this->errors[] = $image->getErrors();
            }
        }

        return $db->commit();
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is how I'm calling the function:

```
if($this->post->newPost($post_title, $post_category, $post_instructions, $post_instructionImages)) {
    Flash::addMessage('New post added');
} else {
    print_r($this->post->errors);
}
```

What I've tried:

I've tried var_dump and print_r the `$errors` but not even then, nothing get's shown, not even inside the if statement above. I've been trying to understand why that is for literally the past 9 hours, I'm asking as a last resort. I didn't think it'd be necessary but [here](http://codepad.org/0yX18mog) is the imageUpload class.

**Update:**

Here is the validate_post function

```
public function validate_post(){

    if($this->post_title == ''){
        $this->errors[] = 'Post title is required';
    }

    if($this->post_category == ''){
        $this->errors[] = 'Post category is required';
    }

    if($this->post_instructions == ''){
        $this->errors[] = 'Post instructions are required';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the validate_post method?

Comment: I think you just need to check the return value when calling the function. I.e. `if(true===$this->post ...`. Otherwise the error array will be type juggled to true.

Comment: @JonStirling I've added it.

Comment: @jh1711 I'll give it a go.

Comment: `$image = $uploadImage->listen(` then you have `$image->getErrors();` so can you show us what the `->listen` function does?

Comment: @Martin I've included that uploadImage class in the what I've tried part, but here it is http://codepad.org/0yX18mog

Comment: have you looked at your PHP error_log?

Comment: @Martin there's currently no report of errors in the php error_log interesting enough.

Could it be because return $this->errors[] = $image->getErrors(); doesn't actually return false but just a set of errors, so the function just keeps executing, without inserting the data as the $this->errors[] has already been returned hence $db->commit() doesn't run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a logic problem:

```
if($this->post->newPost(...)) {
    Flash::addMessage('New post added');
} else {
    print_r($this->post->errors);
}
```

You're printing the error messages if the return value of the `newPost()` method evaluates to `false`.

```
return $this->errors[] = $image->getErrors();
```

This will append the result of `$image->getErrors()` to the `$this->errors` array and then return `$this->errors`.

`$this->errors` at that point is an array. An array that contains values will always evaluate to `true` in PHP. That's why your if-statement does not display the error messages.

To fix this, explicitly return `false` when something went wrong:

```
$this->errors[] = $image->getErrors();
return false;
```

Comment: that's the conclusion I was starting to come (as you can see in my previous comment to Martin before you posted this) because I was thinking that $this->errors[] doesn't actually return false but just a set of data in an array. It would have taken me awhile to figure this out further though, I appreciate you taking your time to give me a huge hand.